# conditional counting from a CSV

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV of titanic data, with several different columns describing the passengers.

I want to find the percentage of passengers who both survived and where adults.

If you look at the data I have included, you will have a much better picture of what I'm talking about. I can't seem to find anything matching my exact situation online. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the data:

```
     Class    Sex    Age  Survived
1      1st   Male  Child       Yes
2      1st   Male  Child       Yes
3      1st   Male  Child       Yes
4      1st   Male  Child       Yes
5      1st   Male  Child       Yes
6      1st   Male  Adult        No
7      1st   Male  Adult        No
8      1st   Male  Adult        No
9      1st   Male  Adult        No
10     1st   Male  Adult        No
11     1st   Male  Adult        No
12     1st   Male  Adult        No
13     1st   Male  Adult        No
14     1st   Male  Adult        No
15     1st   Male  Adult        No
16     1st   Male  Adult        No
```

Comment: How far have you got so far? Is the data imported? Can you get a selection done? E.g. `titanic[titantic$Age=="Adult" & titanic$Survived == "Yes",]` ? Or a `table` - `table(titanic$Age, titanic$Survived)`? Try googling around for "R titanic analysis" for more info as this dataset is used a *lot* as an example for teaching purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`. The final line will calculate the percentage.

```
library(dplyr)

live_adults <- mydata %>% 
  filter(Survived == "Yes", 
         Age == "Adult") %>% 
  nrow()

(live_adults/nrow(mydata))*100
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am really bad at describing what the heck is going on, and you are a life saver.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept the answer and like it up if it was helpful